# I see the error but the account is valid

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
 SQL> CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION custord (custNo IN number)
 2     RETURN NUMBER
 3     IS cust_tot NUMBER(11,2);
 4     BEGIN
 5        SELECT sum(cust_total_field)
 6        INTO cust_tot
 7        FROM ord
 8        WHERE cust_number_field=custNo;
 9        RETURN(cust_tot);
 10      END;
 11  /

 Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

 SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('customer 102 total is ' || custord(102));
  3  end;
  4  /
  dbms_output.put_line('customer 102 total is ' || custord(102));
                                                    *
  ERROR at line 2:
  ORA-06550: line 2, column 52:
  PLS-00905: object CIS605.CUSTORD is invalid
  ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
  PL/SQL: Statement ignored


  SQL>
```

I see the error but object cis605 is valid. Any ideas what I am missing?

Using the ORD table create a stored function called custord that will use a customer  id (CUSTID) that will return the sum of the specified customer id TOTAL field.
When your function has been stored run the following SQL:
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('customer 102 total is ' || custord(102));
end;

Your output should look like:
Results
Explain
Describe
Saved SQL
History

customer 102 total is 27775.5

Statement processed.

Comment: Do you have privileges on the table ORD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SHOW ERRORS FUNCTION custord
```

Your `custord` function was created with compilation errors, so there is something wrong with it.  This is why you're getting the `object CIS605.CUSTORD is invalid` error.